# Using reactivity (in Shiny) from a function

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am writing a function for my app that will call a process in the background, and monitor the moment it stops. Upon closing the session, the process should be killed, so I want it to be available outside of the function. If I assign the process with the `<<-` sign, something strange happens...

```
library(shiny)
library(processx)


runAsync <- function() {

  mainProcess <<- process$new("sleep", "10")

  procTimer <- reactivePoll(1000, NULL, 
                            checkFunc = function() 
                              mainProcess$is_alive() ,
                            valueFunc = function() 
                                mainProcess$is_alive()
                            )
  
  observeEvent(procTimer(),  {
    if(procTimer()) {print("Begin")} else {print("End")}
    print(  mainProcess)
  })
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("runBtn", "Run async process"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$runBtn, runAsync())  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The first time that the button is clicked, everything works as expected. The output is

```
[1] "Begin"
PROCESS 'sleep', running, pid #####.
[1] "End"
PROCESS 'sleep', finished.
```

On the second time however, observeEvent is triggered twice. On the third time, observedEvent is triggered thrice. And so on... The output when clicking on the button for the third time is

```
PROCESS 'sleep', running, pid 19228.
[1] "Begin"
PROCESS 'sleep', running, pid 19228.
[1] "Begin"
PROCESS 'sleep', running, pid 19228.
[1] "End"
PROCESS 'sleep', finished.
[1] "End"
PROCESS 'sleep', finished.
[1] "End"
PROCESS 'sleep', finished.
```

If I replace the `<<-` assignment with a simple `<-` assignment, that fixes it (at least on the surface), and the problem does not occur.

So, my main question is what is the cause of this behaviour? I'd like to **understand**.

I'd also like to ask a side question : what is a good design for such a function? Is it good practice to start a reactivePoll within a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that everytime you call `runAsync()` you add a new `observeEvent` call, a quick fix would be to introduce a reactive value that checks if the function was already called and then do not add a new `observeEvent` as shown in that example:

```
library(shiny)
library(processx)


runAsync <- function(start) {
  
  mainProcess <<- process$new("sleep", "10")
  
  procTimer <- reactivePoll(1000, NULL, 
                            checkFunc = function() 
                              mainProcess$is_alive() ,
                            valueFunc = function() 
                              mainProcess$is_alive()
  )
  if(isTRUE(reactive_value$start))
  {
    observeEvent(procTimer(),  {
      if(procTimer()) {print("Begin")} else {print("End")}
      print(  mainProcess)
    })
    reactive_value$start <- FALSE
  }

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("runBtn", "Run async process"),
)
reactive_value <- shiny::reactiveValues(start = TRUE)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$runBtn, runAsync(reactive_value))  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The longer solution would be to restrucutre the code in a way that the `observeEvent` call is outside of the `runAsync` function

Comment: Why do you think changing the assignment from      mainProcess **<<-** 
  process$new("sleep", "10")      to    mainProcess **<-** process$new("sleep", "10")     fixes the problem?

Comment: @Sam the problem does not occur when switching from `<<-` to `<-` because the new process isn't visible to all the "old" observers that were created.