# How to close a Shiny App session that runs a long FOR loop by closing browser window or by pressing a button (Shinyapps.io)

Tags: for-loop, shiny, shinyapps

I have a Shiny App deployed on Shinyapps.io that runs a long process in a FOR loop and compiles results into a table that is displayed, once the FOR loop is complete. Depending on the user inputs, this FOR loop process may require up to 20 minutes to complete.

Below is a sample of code that sort of replicates this long process enclosed in a FOR loop.

The problem: If the user starts a long process and then closes their browser, then although the browser is closed and the app is not visible to the user the process seems to be still running for some time (this is according to the app's log on shinyapps.io). During that time it is not possible to reload the app and start working with it again.

**I want to give the user an option to close their session with the app or just to stop the FOR loop process before it completes, if they feel like they want to correct their inputs and restart the process. **

I researched many posts on similar problems that hint at various options, and their pros and cons  (see some of them referenced at the bottom).

I tried them and they do not seem to work for a process that is enclosed into a loop. That is, nothing can be done to stop the session or the process before the loop completes.

On another hand, the session does seem to stop if I just close the browser with the running app and wait for some time (for a minute or more). However, if during that minute or more the user tries to load the app again, the webpage with the app does not load BUT the process then continues to run until the LOOP completes (again according to the app's log on shinyapps.io).

What am I missing here? What option may work to stop the process in the FOR loop or to stop the current session, before it completes.

Thank you.

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(n = 1:1000, 
                 number = c(1:1000)+25)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Long FOR loop process"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton('run', 'Run'),
      actionButton('cancel', 'Cancel')
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tableOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  observeEvent(input$run , {
    
    
    newdf <- df
    newdf$new <- NA
    newdf <- newdf[0,]
    
    withProgress(message = paste("Analyzing ", length(unique(df$n)), "th row in df dataframe"), {
      
      
      a <- nrow(df)
    
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
      
   
      
      incProgress(1/a, detail = paste("Analysis is", round(1/a*100,2), "% complete."))
      
        
        Sys.sleep(1)
        
        nextrow <- nrow(newdf)+1
        
        newdf[nextrow, "n"] <- df$n[i]
        newdf[nextrow, "number"] <- df$number[i]
        
        newdf[nextrow, "new"] <- df$n[nextrow] + df$number[nextrow]
        
        
        print(newdf[nextrow, "new"])
        
    }
      
    }) #progress
    
    
    output$result <- renderTable(newdf)
    
    
  } )
  

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

References to some of the things that I tried:

[How does one terminate all processes upon Shiny app end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69284607/how-does-one-terminate-all-processes-upon-shiny-app-end)

https://community.rstudio.com/t/onstop-function-in-shiny-via-shiny-server-pro/110595/4

[How to stop running shiny app by closing the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306295/how-to-stop-running-shiny-app-by-closing-the-browser-window)

etc.

Comment: R is single threaded. If R is busy you can't stop the loop via the same process. Either you make your loop check for e.g. a stop flag every now and then or you need to run the loop asynchronously in a separate R process. I'd recommend using `library(callr)`. Please see my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76005099/9841389).